# Highstocks : Automaticly cumul datas at the same day

Tags: highcharts

It's possible with Highstocks to automaticly calculate the cumul for datas at the same day (Json datas with timestamp) and display one point per day (not showing hours)??

For exemple : obtain only one point of 100 from this timestamps:

```
    [1248134400000, 30],
    [1248134500000, 30],
    [1248135400000, 40],
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,
This can be done with [`dataGrouping`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping). You would want to pick the `'sum'` type.

Comment: Thanks Wergeld!!! It's working with : dataGrouping: {
            approximation: "sum",
            enabled: true,
            forced: true,
            units: [['day',[1]]]

        },